# How Do I Replace Lines in a for Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

The File I'm editing

```
45940736:1330:0.266667:1602990684:10023084.555000
48545806:16000000:0.000000:9999999999:0.000000
1191125008:1185:37.408333:1602991293:10282893.310000
116776982:1811:0.637500:1602990076:10022476.137000
```

My Code

```
f = open("values", "r+")
lines = f.readlines()

for i in lines:
    if str(IDS) in i:
        spl = i.split(":")
        asset_id = spl[0]
        value = spl[1]
        volume = spl[2]
        updated = spl[3]
        item_age = spl[4]
        new_line = asset_id + ":" + "this is a test" + ":"+ volume + ":" + updated + ":" + item_age
        old_line = i
        print(new_line)
```

How would I replace the line while in the for loop instead of doing

```
lines[0] = new_line
ff = open('values', 'w')
ff.writelines(lines)
```

I can't do that because some files will have 2k values and I need to change all of them.

Comment: Beside the point but, you can make the splitting and joining more elegant: `spl[1] = "this is a test"; new_line = ':'.join(spl)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enumerate()` so you get the index in the list, so you can replace the element.

```
for index, i in enumerate(lines):
    if str(IDS) in i:
        spl = i.split(":")
        asset_id = spl[0]
        value = spl[1]
        volume = spl[2]
        updated = spl[3]
        item_age = spl[4]
        new_line = asset_id + ":" + "this is a test" + ":"+ volume + ":" + updated + ":" + item_age
        old_line = i
        lines[index] = new_line
```